# Backendless, the data is duplicated for every User

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

I am trying to built an online shop website and when i add items to cart, it displays all items to user, because it duplicates the item that were already added with another account

Here is the code to display the items added to cart and to save them in backendless

```
const [cartInfo, setCartInfo] = useState([]);
  function displayCart() {
    Backendless.Data.of("Cart")
      .find()
      .then((response) => {
       if (response.length >= 1) {
         setcartProduct((i) => [...response[0].productID]);
       }
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  function saveCart() {
    Backendless.Data.of("Cart")
      .find()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.length < 1) {
          console.log(cartProduct);
          Backendless.Data.of("Cart")
            .save({productID: cartProduct})
            .then((response) => console.log("all saved"))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } else {
          Backendless.Data.of("Cart")
            .save({
              objectId: res[0].objectId,
              productID: [...res[0].productID, ...cartProduct],
            })
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
              setcartProduct(res.productID);
              console.log(res.productID);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```